# How to run migration generation from console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to try to generate migration inside rails console.

This file is responsible for migration creation (particularly **create_migrate_file** method):

**rails/generators/active_record/migration/migration_generator.rb**

[image]

But, for some reason, in my console I can't call **ActiveRecord::Generators::MigrationGenerator** class.

[image]

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Generators::MigrationGenerator
```

What can I do in this case?

Comment: Why not from the command line?

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first require `rails/generators` and then the file where `ActiveRecord::Generators::MigrationGenerator` is defined.

```
require 'rails/generators'
require 'rails/generators/active_record/migration/migration_generator'

ActiveRecord::Generators::MigrationGenerator
# => ActiveRecord::Generators::MigrationGenerator
```